JHipster-Control-Center Unsatisfied Dependency Exception with Keycloak
Title: JHipster Control Center Unsatisfied Dependency Exception with Keycloak during Startup
Post:
I am encountering an error while starting the JHipster Control Center using Docker Compose in my microservices setup, which includes OAuth2 authentication via Keycloak.
Problem description:
After generating a project skeleton and attempting to set it up using Docker Compose, I run into the following exception:
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'logoutResource' defined in URL ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster"

Project setup:

JHipster application configurations:

gateway_service: Reactive gateway using OAuth2 and Consul for service discovery.
product_service: Microservice with OAuth2, Consul, PostgreSQL, and Elasticsearch.


Generated .yo-rc.json:


{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "workspaces",
    "directoryPath": "./",
    "jhipsterVersion": "8.7.0"
  }
}

Environment details:

OpenJDK version: 21.0.4
Node version: 21.7.3
NPM version: 10.8.3
Docker version: 24.0.7
OS: PopOS

Keycloak Configuration:

Accessible from host using:
curl http://keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster


Sample response includes realm details and token-service URL.


Steps to reproduce:
Run the following Docker Compose commands:
docker compose -f ./src/main/docker/services.yml up -d
docker compose -f ./src/main/docker/jhipster-control-center.yml up

Request for help:
Could anyone guide me on what might be causing this Unsatisfied Dependency Exception with the Keycloak configuration? Are there additional configurations needed for the clientRegistrationRepository to work properly with Keycloak?
Additional details:
If more information is needed, such as detailed configurations from application.yml files or Docker logs, please let me know.

You need to create a mapping in your hosts file to map keycloak to 127.0.0.1.

already was done, gist - shema
